# How to CBC Blowfish encrypt with non hex IV

Tags: c#, encryption, bouncycastle, blowfish, cbc-mode

I am rather new to how encryption works, however, I have been asked to encrypt and decrypt a value using Blowfish CBC encryption. Now I've spent quite some time on this and I thought I had it correct until they sent me the IV they wish me to use which left me very confused. I was under the impression that the IV had to be a hexadecimal value, however, they sent me an IV that looks along the lines of: `cl5PxDOt`.

The code I have managed to produce looks like this:

```
function Run()
{
    var key = "enter your key";
    var value = "Enter your test value";
    var iv = StringToByteArray("enter your 16 char hex value");

    var encryptedValue = CbcBlowfishEncrypt(value, key, iv);
    var decryptedValue = CbcBlowfishDecrypt(encryptedValue, key, iv);
}

private string CbcBlowfishEncrypt(string strValue, string key, byte[] iv)
{
    byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strValue);
    BlowfishEngine engine = new BlowfishEngine();
    CbcBlockCipher blockCipher = new CbcBlockCipher(engine);
    PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(blockCipher);
    KeyParameter keyParam = new KeyParameter(Convert.FromBase64String(key));
    ParametersWithIV keyParamWithIV = new ParametersWithIV(keyParam, iv, 0, 8);

    cipher.Init(true, keyParamWithIV);
    byte[] outputBytes = new byte[cipher.GetOutputSize(inputBytes.Length)];
    int length = cipher.ProcessBytes(inputBytes, outputBytes, 0);
    cipher.DoFinal(outputBytes, length); //Do the final block
    var c = BitConverter.ToString(outputBytes);
    string encryptedInput = Convert.ToBase64String(outputBytes);
    var result = BitConverter.ToString(outputBytes).Replace("-", "");
    return result;
}

private string CbcBlowfishDecrypt(string strValue, string key, byte[] iv)
{
    BlowfishEngine engine = new BlowfishEngine();
    CbcBlockCipher blockCipher = new CbcBlockCipher(engine);
    PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(blockCipher);
    KeyParameter keyParam = new KeyParameter(Convert.FromBase64String(key));
    ParametersWithIV keyParamWithIV = new ParametersWithIV(keyParam, iv, 0, 8);

    cipher.Init(false, keyParamWithIV);
    byte[] out1 = Hex.Decode(strValue);
    byte[] out2 = new byte[cipher.GetOutputSize(out1.Length)];
    int len2 = cipher.ProcessBytes(out1, 0, out1.Length, out2, 0);
    cipher.DoFinal(out2, len2);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(out2);
}

public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
        .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
        .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
        .ToArray();
}
```

I am hoping somebody can tell me how to modify the code above to work with the sample iv of: `cl5PxDOt`.

Edit: Here is what I tried, but I get `pad block corrupted` every time:

```
var newIv = "cl5PxDOt";
var newByteIv = newIv.ToArray().Select(Convert.ToByte).ToArray();
var newDecryptedValue = CbcBlowfishDecrypt(ospToken, key, newByteIv);
//var newDecryptedValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(newIv) -- Also tried this, but same result.
```

> at Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Paddings.Pkcs7Padding.PadCount(Byte[] input)
> at Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher.DoFinal(Byte[] output, Int32 outOff)

Comment: Try to use the ASCII (UTF-8 works) encoding of the IV - same as you do with your `strValue`. Note that the IV of CBC needs to be fully unpredictable for CBC mode to be secure. Oh, and modern ciphers take binary input, usually bytes. That's different from hexadecimals, which are often used to *represent* those bytes in human readable form.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Sorry I'm confused about which line of code you are talking about when you say to use UTF-8? My code crashed on `cipher.DoFinal(out2, len2);` which happens before I call `return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(out2);`

Comment: The IV was what you are talking about right? The IV is now 8 characters for a 8 byte block cipher, where you need an 8 byte IV (for CBC). So if you map 1 character to 1 byte then you would have the right IV size. ASCII will do that, and UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII, so that works as well given the characters in the string.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Sorry, I don't seem to be following still. Any chance you could post code example?

Comment: Sorry, I'm on LInux at the moment, don't have a C# environment handy...

Comment: For the posted IV, the current implementation gives the same result as an UTF8 encoding, namely 0x636c355078444f74, which corresponds to an 8 bytes IV as required for Blowfish. Also, the code works on my machine when a Blowfish compliant key and IV are applied. Perhaps the values you used are inconsistent, e.g. a wrong key. Can you post a full set of sample data: key, IV, plaintext and ciphertext?

Comment: @Topaco see updated question. I added values per your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ciphertext can be decrypted if the key is not Base64 decoded but UTF-8 encoded, i.e. in `CbcBlowfishDecrypt()` (and in `CbcBlowfishEncrypt()`) the line

```cs
KeyParameter keyParam = new KeyParameter(Convert.FromBase64String(key));
```

is to be replaced by

```cs
KeyParameter keyParam = new KeyParameter(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
```

The UTF-8 encoded key has a length of 448 bits, and is thus a valid key ([Blowfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_(cipher)) is defined for key lengths between 32 and 448 bits).

The IV can be UTF-8 encoded in an analog way instead of the current implementation.

Comment: Thank you, this has solved my issue. Small request if you do not mind, please remove the plaintext from your answer. I don't think it is relevant and I would prefer not to have it displayed public.

Comment: Do you know how I can start and award bounty after a question has been answered? I don't see an option anywhere.

Comment: @Bagzli - I know it's possible, but I don't know how it works either.